# moviepy: reduzir video a 100mb

Tags: python

Eu gostaria de saber, se há como diminuir um video a 100mb.
Tenho alguns videos e quero converter-lo a 100mb, independente da qualidade que for ficar.

Nesse exemplo, eu reduzo a 360p, em qualidade

```
import moviepy.editor as mp
clip = mp.VideoFileClip("movie.mp4")
clip_resized = clip.resize(height=360) # make the height 360px ( According to moviePy documenation The width is then computed so that the width/height ratio is conserved.)
clip_resized.write_videofile("movie_resized.mp4")
```

Como faria para reduzir em 100mb? há alguma forma? **(PYTHON 2.7)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Infelizmente não é fácil prever o tamanho que um vídeo comprimido vai ficar, antes de tentar comprimí-lo. Isso depende do conteúdo do vídeo - vídeos onde a imagem fica mais estática gastam menos espaço, enquanto outros vídeos na mesma resolução e duração podem gastar muito mais se o conteúdo dos quadros que o compõem mudar com mais freqência.

O único jeito seria fazer um algoritmo que tenta incrementar a qualidade até que encontre um tamanho ideal:

```
tamanho = 100 * 1024 * 1024 # 100 megabytes
resolucoes = [70, 140, 240, 360, 480, 640, 720, 1080]
clip = mp.VideoFileClip("movie.mp4")
for resolucao in resolucoes:   
    clip_resized = clip.resize(height=resolucao) 
    clip_resized.write_videofile("movie_resized_temp.mp4")
    if os.path.getsize("movie_resized_temp.mp4") > tamanho:
        os.remove("movie_resized_temp.mp4")
        break # Para quando encontrar um tamanho bom
    try:
        os.remove("movie_resized.mp4")
    except OSError:
        pass
    os.rename("movie_resized_temp.mp4", "movie_resized.mp4")
```